# $stmt->execute() : How to know if db insert was successful?

Tags: php, mysqli

With the following piece of code, how do i know that anything was inserted in to the db?

```
if ($stmt = $connection->prepare("insert into table (blah) values (?)")) {
$stmt->bind_param("s", $blah);  
$stmt->execute();           
$stmt->close();                                 
}
```

I had thought adding the following line would have worked but apparently not.

```
if($stmt->affected_rows==-1){$updateAdded="N"; echo "failed";}
```

And then use the $updatedAdded="N" to then skip other pieces of code further down the page that are dependent on the above insert being successful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't `affected_rows` be 0 if nothing had been inserted? Although if nothing had been inserted it would presumably be because `execute` had failed. Have you tried `if ($stmt->affected_rows < 1)`?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) method returns a `boolean` ... so just do this :

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { 
   // it worked
} else {
   // it didn't
}
```

**Update:** since 2022 and beyond, a failed query will throw an error Exception. So you won't have to write any code to "skip other pieces of code further down the page" - it will be skipped automatically. Therefore you shouldn't add any conditions and just write the code right away:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("insert into table (blah) values (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $blah);  
$stmt->execute();
```

If you need to do something in case of success, then just do it right away, like

```
echo "success";
```

You will see it only if the query was successful. Otherwise it will be the error message.

Comment: i took a flier on using this method. i googled to make sure, and it led me to this answer. upvoted so more people will use this in their scripts.

Comment: This does not ensure that an insert ever happened! Only that there was not an error.

Comment: @user1032531: You are correct. An `INSERT ... SELECT` could insert zero rows and return successfully. In the case of OP query...  `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` ... I'm not aware of any scenario where the statement would complete successfully without inserting a row. (It's possible I've overlooked some possibility.)

Comment: The problem with this is that an UPDATE would return true even if it had updated zero records.

Comment: Is there any case where this would not work?  I am doing the if statement above.  I can echo before the execute but I get no echo in either parts of the if statement.  It just dies.  This is when I am inserting when the id already exists.  Do I really need to test if the id exists before doing an insert with MySQLi?

Comment: @DanZen it maybe that you have configured MySQLi to throw exceptions - if you have then you need to surround the execute statement with a try/catch statement - you can then look at the error in the Exception

Comment: @manse - thanks for the response.  I found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41077076/2255555 - the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES was turned on by the server folks - which meant all SQL fields have to have  a default value.  Got the server folks to turn that off and all is good.

Answer (score 35):

Check the return value of $stmt->execute()

```
if(!$stmt->execute()) echo $stmt->error;
```

Note that line of code does perform the execute() command so use it in place of your current $stmt->execute() not after it.

Answer (score 13):

Starting on PHP/8.1.0, the default setting is to throw exceptions on error, so you don't need to do anything special. Your global exception  handler will take care of it, or you can try/catch for specific handling.

---

For older versions, you can check [the manual pages](http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) of whatever function you are using:

> prepare() - returns a statement object or **`FALSE` if an error occurred**.
> bind_param() - Returns `TRUE` on success or **`FALSE` on failure**.
> execute() - Returns `TRUE` on success or **`FALSE` on failure**.
> close() - Returns `TRUE` on success or **`FALSE` on failure**.

In practice, though, this gets annoying and it's error prone. It's better to [configure mysqli to throw exceptions on error](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting) and get rid of all specific error handling except for the few occasions where an error is expected (e.g., a tentative insert that might violate a unique constraint):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Default value used to be `MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF`. On PHP/8.1.0 it changed to `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`.

Comment: I upvoted because of the edit. Every mysqli function can fail, and checking for their return value is not feasible or smart. Enabling mysqli error reporting is the correct way.

Answer (score 7):

You can check the returned value after the execute :

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { 
    // ok :-)
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo count . ' rows updated properly!';
} else {
    // KO :-(
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you mean that you want to know the number of affected rows you can use [rowCount on the pdo statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

```
$stmt->rowCount();
```

after execute;

if you are talking about error handling I think the best option is to set the errmode to throwing exteptions and wrap everything in a try/catch block

```
try
{
    //----
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Other way:

```
if ($stmt->error){
        echo "Error";
    }
    else{
        echo "Ok";
    }
```