# mysql can not insert because no default value?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with exactly the same schema.  I can insert into one table but not another.  The one that fails complains about no default value.  Here's my create statement for the table

```
CREATE TABLE `t_product` (
  `product_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `prod_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `prod_date` date NOT NULL,
  `prod_meta` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_key` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_desc` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_code` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `prod_on_promo` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prod_promo_sdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_promo_edate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_promo_price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `prod_discountable` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prod_on_hold` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prod_note` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_alter` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_extdesc` text,
  `prod_img` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `prod_min_qty` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prod_recent` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prod_name_url` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `upc_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When I run this statement in database1, it successfully inserts:

```
insert into t_product (product_id) values ('jlaihello');
```

When I run this exact statement in database2, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'price' doesn't have a default value
```

Why is this error happening only in database2?  As far as I can tell, the difference between database1 and database2 are:

database1 uses mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.3

and

database2 uses mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

How do I make database2 behave like database1?

EDIT
There are hundreds of tables affected by this. Basically we're moving a database over to a new server. And I did a mysqldump from db1, and  imported into db2. t_product is just ONE of the tables affected by this. I'd like to avoid manually modifying the schema for the hundreds of tables.  I prefer a "simple switch" that will make db2 behave like db1.

Comment: `prod_price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,

Comment: Declare your table so `price` supports `NULL`s.  I am guessing that the table definition differs on the two systems.

Comment: Is SHOW CREATE TABLE returning the exact same definitions?

Comment: @Fang yes exact same definition.  I just checked.  Basically we're moving a databse over to a new server.  And I did a mysqldump from db1, and now improted into db2.  t_product is just ONE of the tabels affected by this. There's hundreds of other tables with the same problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'price' doesn't have a default value`

`price decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,`

Set price to null or assign a default value

**EDIT:**

This is caused by the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` SQL mode.

Open phpmyadmin and goto `More` Tab and select `Variables` submenu. Scroll down to find sql mode. Edit sql mode and remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` Save it.

**OR**

You can run an SQL query within your database management tool, such as phpMyAdmin:

```
-- verify that the mode was previously set:
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
-- update mode:
SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode= 'YOUR_VALUE';
```

**OR**

Find the line that looks like so in the mysql conf file:

`sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

Comment above line out and restart mysql server

Comment: Thanks.  I opened my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and then I added the lines `[mysqld]
sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: basically i read in mysql5.7 and going forward, they have STRICT_TRANS_TABLE enabled by default.  So you won't find STRICT_TRANS_TABLE mentioned in the config files.  Instead, you have to explicitly turn it off.

Comment: note to self, I added `[mysqld]
sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` to my /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf and restarted mysql service.

Comment: Thanks. Btw phpmyadmin needs root for this. I had to run these two commands as root for mariadb. SET @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE, 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', '');  SET @@SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', '');

Comment: Thank you, with wamp it's the `my.ini` file and the line is `sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"`

Comment: I used the solution with phpMyAdmin and it worked. But I didn't find any configuration files to modify. I'm on MariaDB 10.5.22. However, the modification made under phpMyAdmin must have modified a configuration file, right...? But where is it...?

Comment: @Juan Try this: The MariaDB configuration file is located at /opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my. cnf, on the MariaDB database server host: The MariaDB official documentation has more details about how to configure the MariaDB database.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, the default for column `price` is missing in the second database. To check this you should output your table structure:

```
describe database2.t_product;
```

OR

```
show create table database2.t_product;
```

and check if the default is defined.

You can alter your table and add the missing default constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE database2.t_product MODIFY COLUMN decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

**EDIT**

Based on comments and [specification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) (data type default values), I think there is a difference in sql_mode of the MySQL:

> For data entry into a NOT NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT
>   clause, if an INSERT or REPLACE statement includes no value for the
>   column, or an UPDATE statement sets the column to NULL, MySQL handles
>   the column according to the SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs for transactional
>   tables and the statement is rolled back. For nontransactional tables,
>   an error occurs, but if this happens for the second or subsequent row
>   of a multiple-row statement, the preceding rows will have been
>   inserted.
>
> If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit
>   default value for the column data type.

So, if strict mode is not enabled for the first database, INSERT/UPDATE is allowed and storing the default value of that type (a 0 decimal)

Comment: Hey Alexei, there are hundreds of tables affected by this.  Basically we're moving a databse over to a new server. And I did a mysqldump from db1, and now imported into db2. t_product is just ONE of the tabels affected by this. I'd like to avoid manually modifying the schema for the hundreds of tables.

Comment: Yes, but can you at least check the following? In the second database, drop one affected table, create it again, describe it and check if the default is there?

Comment: @Alexei - just a hunch but, couldn't STRICT_TRANS_TABLES be involved?

Comment: @Alexei - i dropped the table in second database, ran the create statement again.  When I did a show create table and a describe t_product, the output is exactly the same as database1.t_product.  database2.t_product still can not insert unless I explicitly set the default value in the create table statement.

Comment: Exactly, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. I'll update the answer John

Comment: @John - I think `tcsh` is right and I remembered about being able to make inserts in some tables, into not null columns and no defaults. Now, I know how it was possible :)

Comment: @John - updated my answer for you with how to do that.