# Getting Error While Inserting record via Laravel to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

While Inserting record via Laravel, I got below error :

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'category' doesn't have a 
default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `content`, 
`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (tip, tip, 2017-02-21 10:25:28, 
2017-02-21 10:25:28))
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql can not insert because no default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077044/mysql-can-not-insert-because-no-default-value)

Comment: It means that the column `category` doesn't have a value, i.e. it requires one (defined in your schema), but you haven't given it a value in your query.

Comment: You cannot avoid to put a value for `category`

Comment: how i can do it idont understand

Comment: u mean from form.blade ?

Comment: Please try this: `insert into `posts` (`title`, `content`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('tip', 'tip', '2017-02-21 10:25:28', 
'2017-02-21 10:25:28')`

Comment: i have this in form.blade

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('category') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    {!! Form::label('category', 'Category', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::select('category', ['technology', 'tips', 'health'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! $errors->first('category', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

Comment: insert it in php my admin ?

Comment: ok .. i change it to null instead of none 
http://imgur.com/wEEnD4e

Answer (score 0):

This is an SQL error and it do not relates with `php` or `laravel`.

And the error is clearly mentioned:

> Field `category` doesn't have a default value.

Which means `category` is defined as a `NOT NULL` value, so you cannot exclude that column in your query.

**To remove this:**
Just Execute Following SQL on your MySQL-Client :

```
ALTER TABLE `posts` MODIFY COLUMN `category` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: i change it to null instead of none imgur.com/wEEnD4e

Comment: How you can pass NULL to  `NOT NULL` column ?

Comment: so what i have to do ??

Comment: Either remove the NOT NULL for this column of provide some value

Comment: from where i have delete it

Comment: @mary, Update your migration, and add `->nullable()` or rather create a new migration and add `->nullable(true)` then in down function use `->nullable(false)` on the field